# Java Regular expression for exacted matched case

Tags: java, regex

I have been struggling to find the matched string(s) with Java Regular expression for the syntax `{//<some string>/<some String>}`

My regular expression should return with these matched cases: {//data/process_id}

Below is the String which i want to find matched syntax:

```
@process_id={//data/process_id}#@history_id={//data/history_id}#@Pdataxml={//data/dataxml}#@Prules =_UNESCAPEXMLVALUE({//data/rules})#@submitted_by={//data/submitted_by}#@table_definition={//data/table_definition}
```

I have tried with below regx pattern but it did not work:
`[a-zA-Z_/\\[\\]\\(\\)0-9|]+`

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You question is not clear, please add proper question with input and output

Comment: Regular expression should match with this string format : {//<some string>/<some string>}

Comment: The regexp you tried is not even marginally similar to what you want to match. I wonder how you came up with it.

Comment: @Henry, i have tried with this pattern as well but did not work:  [{//a-zA-Z0-9}] , could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: try regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with a Matcher:

```
"\\{//([^/]+)/([^/}]+)}"
```

The parts are captured in groups 1 and 2.

Like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{//([^/]+)/([^/}]+)}").matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String part1 = m.group(1);
    String part2 = m.group(2);
    // do something with the parts
}
```

To just grab the whole thing, which would be got from `m.group()`, use this regex:

```
"(?<=\\{)//[^/]+/[^/}]+(?=})"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\{\/\/[^\/{}\s]*\/[^\/{}\s]*\}
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/qs8pS3/2/)

**code:**

```
String input = "@process_id={//data/process_id}#@history_id={//data/history_id}#@Pdataxml={//data/dataxml}#@Prules =_UNESCAPEXMLVALUE({//data/rules})#@submitted_by={//data/submitted_by}#@table_definition={//data/table_definition}";
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\/\\/[^\\/{}\\s]*\\/[^\\/{}\\s]*\\}").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(allMatches);
```

**output:**

```
[{//data/process_id}, {//data/history_id}, {//data/dataxml}, {//data/rules}, {//data/submitted_by}, {//data/table_definition}]
```